# Default config.xml?

Tags: cmusphinx, sphinx4

On [this page of the documentation](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/doc/sphinx4/edu/cmu/sphinx/util/props/doc-files/ConfigurationManagement.html), at the bottom, it says:

> You can find full examples of Sphinx-4 configuration file in sources. For example, check the file
> sphinx4/src/apps/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/transcriber/config.xml

Well, I looked, and there is no `config.xml` in that directory, and there is no such file in any of the other folders inside of `demo` either.

So where can one find a default config file to use to get started with?

If I just do  `Configuration configuration = new Configuration();`, would that be good enough to start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently found out that what you suggest is not enough. Take a look at the latest code on the Github repository. There is a default.config.xml file at https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/tree/master/sphinx4-core/src/main/resources/edu/cmu/sphinx/api, and the path to it is set in the Context class in package edu.cmu.sphinx.api:

```
public Context(Configuration config)
    throws IOException, MalformedURLException
{
    this("../sphinx4/sphinx4-core/src/main/resources/edu/cmu/sphinx/api/default.config.xml", config);
}
```

Comment: Don't we need to configure config.xml explicitly?